# Intuition/derivation for Cauchy's repeated integral formula?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration
I'm referring to this formula due to Cauchy. The wiki page has a proof, but what I'm looking for is a more direct derivation or insight into how Cauchy went about obtaining this result. The Wikipedia page proves the formula but doesn't really "derive" it from scratch. Does anyone have an idea of how one could reproduce the result without knowing what it is at first? Thanks!

Comment: do you know what is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) ? if $f(x) = 0$ for $x < a$ then $\int_a^x f(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt = f \ast u(x)$ where $u(x)$ is the unit step function, and the twice integration is the convolution with $u \ast u(x)$, etc.

Comment: @user1952009 thank you for your response! Yes I do, but could you elaborate more?

Comment: elaborate on what ? let $a= 0$, and $u(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$, $u(x) = 0$ otherwise. the definition of the convolution is $u \ast u(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t) u(x-t) dt = \int_0^x u(t) u(x-t) dt = x$ so $\int_0^x \int_0^{t_2} f(t_1) dt_1dt_2 = u \ast \int_0^x f(t) dt = u \ast u \ast f(x) = x\ast f(x)$. by induction you also get $ \underbrace{u \ast \ldots \ast u}_{n}(x) = \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ and $$\underbrace{\int_0^x \ldots \int_0^{t_2}}_n f(t_1) \underbrace{dt_1 \ldots dt_n}_n = f \ast  \underbrace{u \ast \ldots \ast u}_{n}(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \frac{t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} dt$$